# find key by value from object where values in array using underscore lib in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
  "first": ["ping", "route"],
  "Second": ["quick ", "Upload"],
  "Third": ["Custom", "Media"]
}
```

find key by value like:  findKey("Media") -> Third

Answer (score 1):

Use with [`Array#filter`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQnKaSwvnTAhUKro8KHZ0LCN0QFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHgB7IyOa22NG7kCsGZ1ldwMUmkiA) .Iterate the Object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) .Then check with [`array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=example) the value is present in array .Finally get the respected array key from filter

```js
var obj = {
  "first": ["ping", "route"],
  "Second": ["quick ", "Upload"],
  "Third": ["Custom", "Media"]
}

function findkey(val){
return Object.keys(obj).filter((a,b)=> (obj[a].includes(val)))[0]
}

console.log(findkey('Media'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more step by step answer below, which may give you more insight in what's happening, but prasad's one works in the same way with one line.

```js
var obj = {
  "first": ["ping", "route"],
  "Second": ["quick ", "Upload"],
  "Third": ["Custom", "Media"]
}

function findKey(obj, string) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      arr.push({key: key, value: obj[key]})
    }
  }
  return arr.find(function(el) { return el.value.includes("Media")}).key
}

console.log(findKey(obj, "Media"));
```